# Replace a value in file with next char matching using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to modify the value in a class file with the given variable name and value in it.I need to modify the value between two characters.

ex file content:

```
public boolean ISDEV = false;
```

sample part of the Batch Script :

```
set "searchstring=%1"
 set "valuestring=%2"
 set "textFile=Input.txt"

 FOR /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%"') do (
 set "line=%%i"
  >>"%textFile%" !line:%searchstring%=%valuestring%!
 )
```

The above script will work directly for replace the search string with valuestring and my requirement is to change the value of ISDEV to true.
Like example `public boolean ISDEV = true;`

My plan is to modify the value of variable after getting the text to start from the next to variablename (ISDEV) **=** to **;**

Can anyone tell me how to find the characters from = to ; to replace the new value.

Comment: You could search the SO little bit before posting.  This is nearly a duplicate question to *Batch script to find and replace a string in text file without creating an extra output file for storing the modified file* - 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra

Comment: [Sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) does not work when the search string contains `=`, because this character separates the search from the replace string; you could use [`for /F`](http:ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) asl an alternative to split your lines...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file : how to search and replace a string that have an "=" inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724410/batch-file-how-to-search-and-replace-a-string-that-have-an-inside)

Answer (score 2):

This batch code works for the example to toggle in line with `ISDEV` the value `false` to `true` or the value `true` to `false`.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
if not exist Input.txt goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SearchString=%~1"
set "TextFile=Input.txt"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%TextFile%") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    if not "!Line:%SearchString%=!" == "!Line!" (
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=;=" %%J in ("!Line!") do (
            for /F %%V in ("%%~J") do set "Value=%%V"
        )
        if "!Value!" == "false" (
            set "Line=!Line:false=true!"
        ) else if "!Value!" == "true" (
            set "Line=!Line:true=false!"
        )
    )
    echo !Line!>>"%TempFile%"
)
move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%"
endlocal
```

But a batch file solution is in general a bad idea for this task. Windows **command line** interpreter is not designed for string changes in text files. It is designed to execute commands and applications. There are lots of script interpreters which are better for making changes in text files like VBScript, JScript, PowerShell, Python, Perl, ...

The batch file above reads each non empty line not starting with a semicolon from file `Input.txt` and assigns it to environment variable `Line` whereby everything between two exclamation marks with both `!` or from an exclamation mark to end of line are removed on command line `set "Line=%%I"` because of enabled delayed environment variable expansion. In other words this batch file cannot be used to process a text file containing empty lines, lines starting with `;` and lines containing one or more `!`.

The **IF** condition checks if the line contains the search string passed with argument 1 to the batch file by comparing the line with all occurrences of search string substituted case-insensitive by an empty string with the unmodified line. The two compared strings are not equal if the line contains the search string at least once.

In case of line really contains `ISDEV`, one more **FOR** is used to get the string after first occurrence of an equal sign or a semicolon assigned to loop variable `J`.

A third **FOR** loop is used to remove all spaces/tabs around the value read from file.

If the remaining value is case-sensitive either `false` or `true`, the appropriate string substitution is executed to replace all `false` case-insensitive in the line by `true` or all `true` by `false`.

The unmodified or modified line is output and this output is redirected into a temporary file which is finally moved over input file.

---

Here is one more batch file which is much slower as above. It replaces the current value by the string specified as second argument. And it handles lines containing an exclamation mark correct.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
if "%~2" == "" goto :EOF
if not exist Input.txt goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SearchString=%~1"
set "NewValue=%~2"
set "TextFile=Input.txt"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%TextFile%") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    call :ProcessLine
)
move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%"
endlocal

rem Avoid a fall through to subroutine below.
goto :EOF

:ProcessLine
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!Line:%SearchString%=!" == "!Line!" goto OutputLine
for /F "tokens=2 delims=;=" %%J in ("!Line!") do (
    for /F %%V in ("%%~J") do set "OldValue=%%V"
)
set "Line=!Line:%OldValue%=%NewValue%!"
:OutputLine
echo !Line!>>"%TempFile%"
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

But this batch file skips also all empty lines and lines starting with `;`.

---

This third batch file keeps empty lines and lines starting with `;`.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
if "%~2" == "" goto :EOF
if not exist Input.txt goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SearchString=%~1"
set "NewValue=%~2"
set "TextFile=Input.txt"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N /C:"^" "%TextFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    set "Line=%%J"
    if not defined Line echo/>>"%TempFile%"
    if defined Line call :ProcessLine
)
move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%"
endlocal

rem Avoid a fall through to subroutine below.
goto :EOF

:ProcessLine
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!Line:%SearchString%=!" == "!Line!" goto OutputLine
for /F "tokens=2 delims=;=" %%K in ("!Line!") do (
    for /F %%V in ("%%~K") do set "OldValue=%%V"
)
set "Line=!Line:%OldValue%=%NewValue%!"
:OutputLine
echo !Line!>>"%TempFile%"
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

But lines starting with one or more `:` are in modified `Input.txt` without the colon(s) at beginning of the line.

---

Finally let us look on how easy string replaces in text files can be on using the right scripting language, for example JScript installed also with Windows which supports regular expression replaces.

We are using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript stored in same directory as the batch file below.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
if "%~2" == "" goto :EOF
if not exist Input.txt goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(%~1[ \t]*=[ \t]*)[^;]+" "$1%~2" /F "Input.txt" /O -
```

It would be of course possible to do the entire task with `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe` and an appropriate script file or `powershell.exe` and an appropriate PowerShell script.

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~n0` (name of batch file without path and extension)
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `jrepl.bat /? | more`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and answer on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)