# How do I delete text before a pattern using a batch script

Tags: batch-file

Using a batch script, how do I delete the following pattern from the start of a file?

```
DN: CN=ACME Test,OU=ACME Test Company,O=ACME Big Org    someObject;binary:
```

There is a space character after binary: that needs deleting too.

The file contains:

```
DN: CN=ACME Test,OU=ACME Test Company,O=ACME Big Org    someObject;binary: MI...
```

The ... indicates lots more character after the MI

I just need the MI and all the characters the follow it to be in the file after the batch script has run

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is answered here

[Batch script to find and replace a string in text file without creating an extra output file for storing the modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra)

but instead of taking in the "replace=%2" as an argument and replacing with that, you can just replace with an empty string (or pass an empty string in as the parameter if it will never change)

Answer (score 1):

with dcod's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076141/2152082) you would have to know the first part of the string to replace it with nothing. His link is nearly fine, but to delete from the start to (including) `binary;`, instead of

```
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
```

use

```
set "line=!line:*binary: =!"
```