# ssrs Datasource CSV semi colon delimited giving long column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a tool that generates csv automatically but in semicolon ;however when I run the query in SSRS   it is giving only one column to all the fields in the report. When I changed the semicolon with comma, it is working well.
I want to modify or change the settings in the SSRS to give the correct format. I run the query for example  the csv has sample1;sample2;sample3;;;; a;b;c; , the output is giving sample1;sample2;sample3;;;; a;b;c;

I tried changing the reportingservices.config  this way but not working

> [image]

```
 <Extension Name="Semicolon" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
                <OverrideNames>

    <Name Language="en-US">CSV (semicolon delimited)</Name>
                 <Name Language="en-EN">CSV (semicolon delimited)</Name>


                </OverrideNames>
                <Configuration>
                    <DeviceInfo>
             <FileExtension>csv</FileExtension>
                        <FieldDelimiter>;</FieldDelimiter>
<SuppressLineBreaks>True</SuppressLineBreaks>
                    </DeviceInfo>
                </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```

I want this kind of output.

```
sample1 |  sample2 | sample3
     a          b         c
```

Any idea on how to do this in SSRS.

Comment: Just curious.. did you restart the RS services after the change?

Comment: Just restarted the services again this morning and also enable protocol fot TCP/IP on protocol for SQL Server. Reporting Services is working now, but the semicolon csv is not in the right format

Comment: This is all very confusing. What are you _viewing_ this file in? What are you _generating_ this file in?

Comment: @Nick. I am using SSRS to connect to csv and run query. It is a semi colon csv file, Because is a tool that generate it automaticall, I can not just change manually everytime the tool is running to comma delimited file. Check the screen shot added

Comment: So.... really you are connecting to a _database table_ from SSRS. And that database table is populated from a semicolon delimited file. And you can't change the program that generates the file. How are you importing the file into the database? You've missed out some really fundamental things in your explanation

Comment: We are not importing files to DB. I have already connected it through ODBC and tested succesfully. When  I changed  the semicolon with comma in the file and it is working good. However, I do not want comma delimited file. What do you think?  Is there no way to handle semicolon this way.I am not expert in this........ what can I do ?

Comment: If using ODBC to connect to the semicolon separated file.. then can you not specify semicolon in ODBC as your separator rather than the comma?

Comment: How ?  I have no idea. Please tell me how. Is it in the odbc settings

Comment: I'm only going by the comment you made above.. When setting up the ODBC to your data source, you should be able to define the separator (Define Format). Unless I'm wrong.. haven't had to do this in a while!

Comment: I have not seen the option.

Comment: I have decided to just write a batch file to replace the semicolon immediately the csv is generated by the .exe application. The example to replace is also in this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just write a batch file to replace the semicolon immediately the csv is generated by the .exe application. The example to replace is also in this link :  [Batch script to find and replace a string in text file without creating an extra output file for storing the modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion




::  rem   editing and replacing  a text file without redirecting the output to file 

@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=%;"
    set "replace=%,"

    set "textFile=try2.csv"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
pause
```

Comment: You should b able to define a custom delimiter in the schema.ini file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nick. That is interesting. where is the schema.ini located in the folder. I read the page now !

Comment: Ok. I have read it now. I have to create schema.ini and define what I want. should i use Format=Delimited(custom character) as the fomat type  since this is semicolon