# How to edit a value from XML in .bat script

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I am days trying to change a value in an XML file I found some things and I was adapting but I still didn't have success I need to change the value of the TAG showLockNotifications from 0 to 1 but when running the script it changes all lines .

could someone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<useroptions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="0" /> <-- ** I'd like to change only this value to 1**
  <useroption name="showLowBatteryNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showBacklightingAdjustments" value="1" />
  <useroption name="automaticCheckForUpdates" value="1" />
  <useroption name="collectAnonymousData" value="0" />
  <useroption name="isAutoBackupEnabled" value="1" />
  <useroption name="HideAnalytics" value="0" />
  <useroption name="showFlowNotificationIcon" value="1" />
</useroptions>
```

I have tried this code but it replaces all lines in the file...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=1

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (options.xml) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "newLine=!line:name="showLockNotifications">=!"
   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      set "newLine=  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="%anotherVariable%" />"
   )
   echo !newLine!
)) > newFile.xml
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<useroptions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />
</useroptions>
```

Comment: You would be better off using a language that has a native method to read and write xml then trying to brute force it with a batch file.

Comment: Does [Batch script to find and replace a string in text file without creating an extra output file for storing the modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141) help?

Comment: It can be done, but it's not wise. Batch files do not contain modules or packages that can interpret xml format. When you try and do it with a batch file, your are reading it as plain text and brute force re-writing it, hoping you'll get a proper result.. Just wait until you experience some sudden special characters and suddenly your xml turns upside down like a flapjack in a cast iron pan.

Comment: Morgan, there are multiple answers to your question now, and I have noted that you have visited this site since they were provided. Please can you review those answers, and provide relevant feedback to their authors. _You could also, optionally, reconsider your accepted answer based upon your testing of those too_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope you like this solution :-)

Edited with more clear code optimization:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=1

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (options.xml) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "newLine=!line:showLockNotification=!"

   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      set "newLine=  <useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="%anotherVariable%" />"
      > con echo !newLine!
      echo !newLine!
   )
   if "!newLine!" equ "!line!" (
      > con echo !line!
      echo !line!
   )
 )
) > newFile.xml

pause
```

Explaination of mistakes in your code:

- The string substitution format was not propertly used
- the loop print only the "newLine" but not the old lines

Comment: @Acca Emma Why one loop for display and a second loop  to change the file ? You can use, for example,  the stderr stream to do both in one loop.

Comment: Well, I don't really like this, because repeated code is never a good idea (which could be avoided by just using the second loop with inserted commands like `> con echo !newline!` and `> con echo !line!` at the proper locations); but what I miss most is an explanation of what is going on in your code…

Comment: @aschipfl: I cleared the code and I text an explaination about mistakes, I hope now can be more clear for the community :-)

Comment: Removing the `echo` commands without the `> con` prefix will result in an empty output file…

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, this is much safer and better done using something which has support for xml file handling.

The following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) gets such support from [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```sh
@powershell.exe -NoProfile "[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'options.xml' -Raw;"^
 "$xml.SelectSingleNode(\"//useroption[@name='showLockNotifications']\").SetAttribute('value','1');"^
 "$xml.Save('newFile.xml')"
```

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself a lot of headache I'd recommend an XML-parser like [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) or [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.

```
xmlstarlet.exe ed -u "//useroption[@name='showLockNotifications']/@value" -v 1 options.xml
```

```
xidel.exe -s options.xml -e "x:replace-nodes(//useroption[@name='showLockNotifications']/@value,function($x){attribute {name($x)} {'1'}})" --output-format=xml --output-declaration='^<?xml version="1.0"?^>'

xidel.exe -s options.xml -e ^"^
  x:replace-nodes(^
    //useroption[@name='showLockNotifications']/@value,^
    function($x){attribute {name($x)} {'1'}}^
  )^
" --output-format=xml --output-declaration='^<?xml version="1.0"?^>'
```