# How to Echo text that includes ">>"

Tags: windows, text, cmd, automation

I'm new to Linux and Bat Scripts so this question might seem easy to many of you.

I have a bat script that is supposed to overwrite a file with text.
I'm unable to copy all the text because it includes ">>" within the text i want to copy.

Example:

**ECHO **"echo -e Text_to_copy >> /home/fileA.csv" >A.txt****

The code above works but the quotations (") are copied as well and I need them removed from my end result (A.txt).
If I use apostrophes (') instead of quotations then, I only get partial text added to my end file (**echo -e Text_to_copy**)

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: If you're on Linux, you should be using a bourne shell variant, and `echo "foo >> bar"` will work just fine without writing the quotes.

Comment: Im using a BAT script , after writing into the file I need to add the text to a remote server.
I'm using PLINK for that. Would "bourne shell variant" work for that as well?

Comment: `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh` are typical shells in Linux.  Modifying files on a remote host is typically done via `ssh` or `rsync` or `scp`.  If you're going to learn Linux, it's probably best to become familiar with the standard toolset.

Comment: Linux does not support BAT scripts. Please re-tag the question for Windows and cmd.exe if Linux is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Bash works as expeced:

```
andrew@andrew-Ubuntu:~$ echo "echo -e Text_to_copy >> /home/fileA.csv" >A.txt
andrew@andrew-Ubuntu:~$ cat A.txt 
echo -e Text_to_copy >> /home/fileA.csv
andrew@andrew-Ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

It may fix your Problem

IF YOU WANT TO ADD MORE LINES THEN ADD INTO `INFORMATION` FIELD

MAKE SURE TO USE DOUBLE-QUOTES (") WHILE ADDING INFORMATION

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "textFile=a.txt"

::----------Information--------
echo "echo -e Text_to_copy >> /home/fileA.csv">%textfile%

::-----------------------------

    set se="
    set rl=

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%se%=%rl%!
        endlocal
    )
```

SOURCE : [Batch script to find and replace a string in text file without creating an extra output file for storing the modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141)

Comment: `"` is called "Double-quotes" (or sometimes just "Quotes"). "Inverted commas" are typographical quotes used in text processing. They just don't work in `cmd`