# Find and Replace String causing unknown error in .bat (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to replace some text in a `.yml` file using batch.

My code:

```
@echo off
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )
setlocal enableextensions 

set jruby="%~dp0jruby\bin\jruby"
set someDir="%~dp0..\test\test2"

cd %someDir%
copy /y file.yml test_file.yml > NUL
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in (file.yml) do @set "password=%%i"
echo Your password --- %password% --- will now be encrypted due to security reasons...

%jruby% -S run_file.rb 

for /f "delims=" %%x in (some_file.rb) do set some_key=%%x

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%jruby% -S encrypt_property_for_yaml encrypt %some_key% %password%`) DO (
SET encrypted_pw=%%F
)
echo Random 32-Bit encryption key created: %some_key%
echo Password was encrypted to: %encrypted_pw%
echo.
echo Encrypted password will be saved in file.yml file...

set "replace=%encrypted_pw%"
set "databaseFile=file.yml"
set "search=%password%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%databaseFile%" ^& break ^> "%databaseFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
pause
```

### The error occurs due to this code block

```
set "replace=%encrypted_pw%"
set "databaseFile=file.yml"
set "search=%password%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%databaseFile%" ^& break ^> "%databaseFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
pause
```

The whole thing works perfectly, but as soon as I reach the last `FOR-BLOCK` where the actual replace takes place, I always get the following error:

```
! was unexpected at this time
```

At first I thought it was due to the missing closing bracket on echo, but that still causes the same error.

> *Side note: the method I use to find and replace was originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141)

The funny thing is, when I run the same code in a completely separate .bat file, it works flawlessly, but when I use it with the current batch file including other code, I always get the same error. I tried using `set` instead of `>>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!`

I tried googling, found some similar situations where it  has something to do with the delayedexpansion but I can't seem to get the `FIND and REPLACE` to work.

Comment: Show my an example of an _"encrypted password"_ as defined in your examples.

Comment: @Gerhard something like this: ENC(qQU35msnA699PH9RX18XYQ==) and i checked with echo off, it gets assigned to variable properly

Comment: There's you problem. You need to escape the closing parenthesis as `^)` The code block is seeing it as a closing parenthesis for itself.

Comment: @Gerhard you mean the closing parenthesis on the ENC(qQU35msnA699PH9RX18XYQ==) ? I assign it at SET encrypted_pw=%%F, do i add the ^) after the %%F?

Comment: No. the solution will depend on the following. is the password in double quotes in the file?

Comment: @Gerhard yeah its written in a file in the directory im in. Its in the file.yml and i save the password content into the variable  %password%

Comment: yes, but is the password double quoted in the `yml` file or not. i.e `pass="ENC(qQU35msnA699PH9RX18XYQ==)"` or without `pass=ENC(qQU35msnA699PH9RX18XYQ==)`

Comment: oh im sorry misunderstood, no its without " " @Gerhard

Comment: ok, so directly before  `set "replace=%encrypted_pw%"`  do `set "encrypted_pw=%encrypted_pw:)=^)%"` I must also warn you, should your password contain `!` it will remove it due to `delayedexpansion` so do consider that as well. There are ways around that though.

Comment: I’ll give it a go and if it works, I’d appreciate it if you post it as an answer so I can upvote and accept as solution :) @gerhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords contains closing parathesis which is seen as a closure of the code block. You need to escape the occurrence of each `)`

In the below code snipped, I added the replacement section:

```
set "encrypted_pw=%encrypted_pw:)=^)%"
set "replace=%encrypted_pw%"
set "databaseFile=file.yml"
set "search=%password%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%databaseFile%" ^& break ^> "%databaseFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
pause
```

Alterantively, and even better you can make it even shorter and let it be part of the replacement itself in the loop:

```
set "replace=%encrypted_pw%"
set "databaseFile=file.yml"
set "search=%password%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%databaseFile%" ^& break ^> "%databaseFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace:)=^)%!
    endlocal
)
pause
```

EDIT: to retain open lines.

```
@echo off
set "search=word to search"
set "replace=to replace"
set "databaseFile=file.yml"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%databaseFile%" ^| find /n /v "^"  ^& break ^> "%databaseFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    >>"%databaseFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
pause
```