# Batch script to search & extract a string from a XML file

Tags: batch-file

I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
    <messaging msg="otherfiles.xml" />
    <counter tes="01" />
    <gate address="192.168.1.1:12345" allowed="172.11.1.1"/>
</configuration>
```

The file name is test.xml `test.xml`.

And I have an bat file:

```bash
@echo OFF
set dir="D:\Test"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"address" %dir%\test.xml') do call :job "%%i"
goto :eof

:job
set line=%1
set line=%line:/=%
set line=%line:<=+%
set line=%line:>=+%
set line=%line:*+string+=%
set line=%line:+=&rem.%
echo.%line%>>%dir%\output.txt

:eof
```

I need output like this:

```
192.168.1.1:12345
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use all this search and replace, if you use `delims` and `tokens` with `for`:

```
@echo off
set "Mydir=D:\Test"
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==/" %%i in (
             'findstr /c:"address" "%Mydir%\test.xml"'
             ) do echo %%~j
```

see `for /?`, from `cmd` for full usage information.

Note! I changed your variable from `%dir%` to `%Mydir%` as it is not usually a good idea to name anything in batch the same as a system command.

Comment: Thanks.
How if I change xml to <gate address="192.168.1.1:12345" allowed="172.11.1.1"/> and save output to file?

Comment: have a look at my answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212481/find-and-replace-string-causing-unknown-error-in-bat-batch-file) You have to be careful though as you have poison characters in the xml `<` and `>` which you need to ensure does not get translated as redirects.